# Vim: Put newlines around '{' and '}' but not around those inside strings with single quotes or double quotes

Tags: php, vim

As part of cleaning php code, I want to put newlines around '{' and '}' but not around those found in strings with single quotes or double quotes.

What is the vim command to do this?

I did

```
/[{}]
:%s//\r&/g
:%s//&\r/g
```

But it gives newlines around every '{' and '}' including those that occurs inside strings.

`echo 'Hello{world}';`

becomes

```
echo 'Hello
{
world
}
';
```

which I don't want.
Please help.

Comment: maybe thats OT, but you may want to check out https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion perhaps, without posting vimscript (though I cannot think of a regex that will do this in one pass) is to decide upon some marker scheme (I prefer 3 hashes) and do it in stages.

I will be back later with the correct regex (the commands I'm familiar with are not working so well on my windows gvim install)

Step 1: With a regex that searches for anything of the form

```
.*["||'].*{.*}.*["||']
```

(i.e. braces inside quotes) prepend matching lines with your marker

Step 2: Now with a regex search for any lines that match something like:

```
^[^###]\+.*{.*}
```

(i.e. anything with braces and the line not beginning with markers) and put in your returns

Step 3: remove the markers

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2 pass solution, which will also cover the single line comment match.

***1st pass***

```
 g/\(\/\/.*\)\@<!{/s/\('\)\@<!{/\r{\r/g
```

First Part:

```
\(\/\/.*\)\@<!{
```

: ommits lines that are single commented and contain the '{' atom

Second Part:

```
\('\)\@<!{
```

Ommits all `{` matches that are preceded by the `'` character.

Third Part:

```
\r{\r/g
```

Encloses '{' with new line characters

***2nd pass***

```
    g/\(\/\/.*\)\@<!}/s/}\('\)\@!/\r}\r/g
```

The only difference with the 1st pass in functionality is that we match *any* `}` *not followed by* `'`

This *solution* does not include the case where a comment is within a code line i.e

```
$('{improper}').count(function(){var string="lestring"}); //{is not ommited}
```